# Spring Data JPA with Querydsl -- filter by value inside array from URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Assumed that I have 2 entity. The first entity is parent of the second entity with one-to-many relation.

```
class Item {
    String name;
    Integer price;
}

class Order {
    List<Item> items;
    String customerName;
}
```

And I have repository defined like this:

```
interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Order> {
}
```

After that, I have a controller that automatically bind parameter to predicate like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/orders")
class OrderController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    List<Order> list(@QuerydslPredicate Predicate predicate) {
        return orderRepository.findAll(predicate);
    }   
}
```

So, I can query order from repository with a specific filter like this:
`curl -XGET http://localhost/orders?customerName=John`

The problem is that I cannot filter value inside a list. I also try `http://localhost/orders?items.name=Bag` but got `NullPointerException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getField(ReflectionUtils.java:143) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslPredicateBuilder.reifyPath(QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java:185) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    ...
```

So, the questions is, how can I filter value inside list with Spring JPA and Querydsl.

Note: I use spring boot 1.3.4 with querydsl-jpa 3.7.4

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to tweak the binding through the means described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe), QuerydslBinderCustomizer in particular?

Comment: @OliverGierke I tried to add custom binding but it also fail. I think the problem is around `QuerydslPredicateBuilder#reifyPath` which is it tries to access path of `item.name` but the field of `ListPath<QItem>` don't have field name that cause `NullPointerException`. I'm also trying to implement it myself, but my knowledge to code base is very little. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a two-fold bug actually. Our translation to dot-names is broken for that particular scenario, even if you defined a custom binding like this:

```
bindings.bind(user.addresses.any().street).as("alias").first(…);
```

which would be a solution to work around our failure to handle the collection path traversal out of the box.

I've filed [DATACMNS-883](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-883) for you to solve both problems:

1. Collection path traversals should automatically result in the call to `any()` added during path reification.
2. Manually declared (and aliased) path bindings including an `any()` traversal should work properly.

Fix is available (try the latest snapshots) and scheduled for both the Ingalls milestone and a Hopper and Gosling service release.